# Is there a replacement for FormSection(reduxForm) in React-final-form. If not how to implement it in react-final-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-final-form

I'm migrating from Redux form to react final form. Is there a replacement for FormSection of ReduxForm in react-final-form?

I saw a solution [here](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/25) by using the dot notation. However, my app might have a lot of nested formsections. So its not possible to determine and add the  names accordingly. So is there an replaceable implementation for Formsection in react-final-form?

I'm currently trying out using a context. However this requires changing the 'name' prop to `${val}.${prevName}` everywhere. Thus, it would be better to have an easier implementation if possible

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. There are two approaches:

- [Reusable Field Groups](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#reusable-field-groups) – if you know the exact fields you want to reuse under some prefix
- [Prefixed Fields](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#prefixed-fields) – if you want to prefix any arbitrary set of fields (*but you must use a modified `Field` component*)

The latter example I just wrote as a response to this question. These are not included in the library because they are so relatively simple to add to your codebase manually.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Erik . This is what I was looking for. However, this doesn't work during migration. Is there a complete migration guide from redux-form  to react-final-form?

Comment: React-final-form-arrays work perfectly in place of formarrays. However Fields don't seem to pass the props similar to redux-form in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-fields-component-xi3tz?fontsize=14) example (This is a modified version of the original Fields Example).

Comment: This options dont replace FormSection from ReduxForm because you need to create a custom Field to append the form prefix. The beauty of FormSection is to use common Fields when necessary.

Comment: The above links have been moved to here: [Reusable Field Groups](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/tree/master/examples/reusable-field-groups), and here: [Prefixed Fields](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/tree/master/examples/prefixed-fields).